# Куряги или куряки?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется куряГи или куряКи?

Answer (score 2):

Слово зафиксировано - ***куряка***. И даже с обоснованием.

На скриншоте не помещаются строки в длину, уходят за край экрана, а скопированное правило не сохраняет шрифтовых выделений.

Пойдём на компромисс...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Научного немножко больше, чем требуется, но всё лучше, чем гадание на кофейной гуще.

> Суффикс -|а|г(а). Существительные общ. р. с суф. -|а|г(а), орфогр.
>   -яг(а) (фонемат. |аг|) называют лицо, производящее действие, названное мотивирующим словом. Мотивирующие глаголы - несов. вида,
>   преимущественно беспрефиксальные, I и Х кл. с основой на -а и -и;
>   конечная гласная основы отсутствует: бродяга, деляга (разг.), доходяга
>   (прост.), нудяга (прост.), работяга (разг.), трудяга (разг.).
>   Парно-твердые согласные перед суф. смягчаются: делать - деляга,
>   работать - работяга. Сюда же слово жен. р. летяга (животное). Ударение
>   на суффиксе (акц. тип А). Тип продуктивен в разг. речи и просторечии;
>   все слова имеют фамильярную окраску.
>
> Суффикс -ак(а). Существительные муж. и общ. р. с суф. -ак(а), орфогр.
>   также -як(а) (фонемат. |ак|) имеют то же значение, что и в предыдущем
>   типе, но с оттенком неодобрения или иронии. Мотивирующие глаголы -
>   несов. вида, беспрефиксальные, I и V кл. с инф. основой на -а, Х кл.
>   на -и: гуляка, зевака, кривляка, кусака, ломака, писака (слова общ.
>   р.); рубака, служака, вояка (слова муж. р.). В вояка отсутствует
>   финаль -|о|ва- глагольной основы (воевать), в остальных - конечная
>   гласная. Ударение на суффиксе (акц. тип А). Тип продуктивен в разг.
>   речи и просторечии: бояка, задавака (задаваться - (зазнаваться),
>   прост.), читака, **куряка**, окказ. забывака (В. Быков).

[ИСТОЧНИК](http://rusgram.narod.ru/208-255.html)

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, *куряги*. *Курить - куряги* по аналогии с *бродить - бродяги*.